# Finding the marginal density of $ce^{-x^2-y^2-xy-x}$

Tags: calculus, statistics

In my probability class, we've started studying joint distrubutions and I've been tasked with the following problem: Let $(X,Y)$ have joint density $ce^{-x^2-y^2-xy-x}$, where $c>0$ is some constant. Find the marginal density of $X$.

What this amounts to is evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ce^{-x^2-y^2-xy-x} dy$. I need some help evaluating this integral because nothing I've tried has worked so far. I began by breaking it up and bringing out the terms with $x$:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ce^{-x^2-y^2-xy-x} dy & = ce^{-x^2-x}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2-xy} dy \\
\end{align*}
However this hasn't given me anything of worth, so maybe breaking it up like this isn't the best approach. I've also tried completing the square in the exponent for both $x^2$ and $y^2$ terms but that hasn't helped either. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline:** I expect you have already bumped into the standard normal distribution, which has density function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}$. In particular, we have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\,dt=\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Now we find 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(y^2+xy)}\,dy.$$ Note that $y^2+xy=(y+x/2)^2-x^2/4$. So we want 
$$e^{x^2/4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(y+x/2)^2}\,dy.$$

Make the substitution $y+x/2=t/\sqrt{2}$.

**Remark:** Or else perhaps you already know $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}\,du$. Then a substitution process similar to the one above will do the job.

Comment: Very nice, thank you. In my early attempts, I tried to see if I could reduce this down to a multivariate gaussian (since I was hoping to get that (x+y)^2 term in the exponent) but I couldn't get anywhere. This worked perfectly.

Comment: You are welcome. I used the cdf of the standard normal, but it is marginally easier to do it as in the remark, if we know the appropriate definite integral.